# expss tab_pivot() not returning anything from inside a for loop

Tags: r, expss

expss looks great for my purpose, but I am having a small problem with it.

**Try 1 (not working)**:
When I use expss on a dataframe everything works fine, but then I want to subset the data frame and then call expss on each subset. To subset and call expss I am using a for loop. The data frame is subset correctly, but expss does not return anything.

```r
municipal_lists <- unique(leeftijd1$Regio)[1:3]

for (i in seq_along(municipal_lists)){
  zx <-subset(leeftijd1, leeftijd1$Regio == municipal_lists[i])
  zx %>%
    expss::tab_rows(Regio) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(`Leeftijdscategorie 1`) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(Perioden) %>%
    expss::tab_stat_cases() %>%
    expss::tab_pivot() 

}
```

**Try 2 (not working)**:
I then created a function of all expss call. When I use this function on a data frame, it works. But if I put this function into a for loop, nothing is returned from the function.

```r
get_table <-function(zx){
    zx %>%
    expss::tab_rows(Regio) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(`Leeftijdscategorie 1`) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(Perioden) %>%
    expss::tab_stat_cases() %>%
    expss::tab_pivot() #%>%


}



municipal_lists <- unique(leeftijd1$Regio)[1:3]

for (i in seq_along(municipal_lists)){
  zx <-subset(leeftijd1, leeftijd1$Regio == municipal_lists[i])
  get_table(zx)

}
```

**Function is working:** A function call works without a for loop, but for whole data frame (with a fixed index)

```r
get_table <-function(zx){
    zx %>%
    expss::tab_rows(Regio) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(`Leeftijdscategorie 1`) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(Perioden) %>%
    expss::tab_stat_cases() %>%
    expss::tab_pivot() 


}



municipal_lists <- unique(leeftijd1$Regio)[1:3]
 zx <-subset(leeftijd1, leeftijd1$Regio == municipal_lists[1])
 get_table(zx)
```

**Direct Call is working:** The simplest form without a for loop or without function call is working as expected.

```r
  zx <- leeftijd1
  zx %>%
    expss::tab_rows(Regio) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(`Leeftijdscategorie 1`) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(Perioden) %>%
    expss::tab_stat_cases() %>%
    expss::tab_pivot()
```

So, how do I get a expss table for each subset of the larger data frame? Could someone guide me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something with result of your calculations inside loop. You can print them, for example:

```
municipal_lists <- unique(leeftijd1$Regio)[1:3]

for (i in seq_along(municipal_lists)){
  zx <-subset(leeftijd1, leeftijd1$Regio == municipal_lists[i])
  zx %>%
    expss::tab_rows(Regio) %>%
    expss::tab_cells(`Leeftijdscategorie 1`) %>%
    expss::tab_cols(Perioden) %>%
    expss::tab_stat_cases() %>%
    expss::tab_pivot()  %>%
    print()

}
```